# Why is my Apache RewriteRule removing hex codes from the target url query string?

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, rewrite, url

I have an apache rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/xy[/]{0,1}$ https://www.example.com/path/file.php?utm_source=Billboard&utm_medium=Print&utm_campaign=MyOrg%20Promo&utm_term=2020FA&utm_context=XY%2C%20border%20state%20abbreviation%20redirect [R]
```

But my target url is actually becoming:

```
https://www.example.com/path/file.php?utm_source=Billboard&utm_medium=Print&utm_campaign=MyOrg0Promo&utm_term=2020FA&utm_context=XYC0border0state0abbreviation0redirect
```

So, it is stripping out the `%2` part of the hex codes in the query string of the target.

I have tried setting the PT, B, NE, QSD, & BNP flags.
I'm on Apache 2.4.6(CentOS), and the BNP flag isn't supported there.

How can I get Apache to leave those codes alone?

Comment: `^/xy[/] {0,1}$` - I assume the _space_ in your regex is just a typo? Otherwise, that is invalid. (This would be the same as simply `^/xy/?$`.)

Comment: You are correct. I fixed it in the original post. Thank-you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `%2` is a *backreference* in mod_rewrite *substitution* strings, that would otherwise refer back to the 2nd captured subpattern in the last matched *CondPattern*. There is none in the example you posted, so this is replaced with an empty string - so it looks like it is simply "stripped".

For any sequence of `%n` (where `n` is 0-9), you need to backslash-escape the `%` to negate its special meaning. eg. `\%20`

Or, use `+` instead of `%20` to escape literal spaces in the query string.

You will need the `NE` flag on the `RewriteRule` to prevent the query string being doubly escaped. (And you should probably be using the `L` flag as well.)

Comment: That solved it! Thanks for the explanation.